# Can I plug corded light fixtures in outlets in ceiling per code?

Tags: cord-and-plug

I  have build a new pole shed. I installed 20 amp switch with 12/2 wire from the switch to 20 amp outlets in the ceiling to power plug in LED lights. I can plug up to 8 LED lights on a 15 amp circuit (according to the packaging). My question: will plugin light fixtures with corded plugs meet code?

Comment: Please refer to the [faq] for types of questions that should be asked here.  Code specific questions are generally off-topic as they vary by region and cannot reliably be answered on a global site like this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a code related question.  Regional in nature, not able to be answered to a wide audience.

Comment: We answer code question all the time, in fact I would guess that close to 80% of electrical question have a code related response or cite a code reference.

Comment: Will the LED lights be behind an installed surface such as a drop ceiling?  Or will the cord and sockets be visible?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Every question should be answered to Code so I'm fairly sure Code questions are on-topic.  It's valuable to have a nationality/territory identified, but OP has made it fairly plain by obvious EFL and use of many North American idioms like 12/2, 20A and 15A.  All those derive from NEC so an NEC answer is appropriate.

Comment: Then the [faq] should probably be updated.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo looks like someone just did. It says national code level questions ok, local variation questions bad.

Answer (score 3):

Corded lights are legal to be plugged into outlets. Although your LED lights are wired for a 15 amp circuit the lamp draws much less, the directions state 8 fixtures for a 15 amp circuit, I would guess the 8 lamps draw a total of 1200w or less,  but in any case the NEC allows manufacturer instructions to override code in some cases as long as the product is listed. NEC 400.8 provides the locations that can't be used but if the outlet is visible (not concealed) it is legal .

Comment: Also, NEC 400.7 explicitly lists luminaires as an allowable use for cordage -- no need to resort to manufacturer instructions.

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to seek forgiveness than to seek permission! Codes vary with location. The important thing here is you are on the right track with wiring the outlets with #12 wire but does it include a ground wire? I never can keep that straight! If'n you have a white, black and a bare wire in your 12-2 then you are good. If'n you are gonna put up 8 lights or less you are good. Both have a comfortable safety factor. Should satisfy any reasonable code. Best you read the code yourself since many "code experts" are like General Aviation mechanics fresh out of A&P school: full of themselves!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Your answer would be improved by removing affectations and storytelling, and it's good that you're disclosing guesswork as guesswork, sometimes you don't have a choice, but if practical do a bit of research to affirm your guess and then state it positively.  You can edit by clicking the word "edit" right below your message (share **edit** delete).

Comment: It's actually quite rare in North America for an AHJ to diverge heavily from the NEC -- most larger AHJs won't diverge unless they see good reason to.  (Some smaller ones have...curious local amendments, though, but those are generally only impactful on a few select parts of the Code)